# Emacs hg ci no longer starting a separate emacs window

Tags: emacs, emacs24, emacs25

On upgrading to emacs25 (ubuntu 18.04) I'm having some issues with mercurial usage.

Previously in emacs24 (ubuntu 16.04) running `hg ci` would start a separate emacs window where you could complete your commit message.

Since the upgrade I get:

```
/usr/bin/sensible-editor: 25: /usr/bin/sensible-editor: /usr/bin/emacs24: not found
```

I've had a look at `sensible-editor` but can't see any specific reference to `emacs24`, I can't see `emacs24` mentioned in the export output either.

I'm wondering how to fix this to get back to the original capability of `hg ci` firing up a new emacs window?

Note this is all being done from within emacs via a `M-x shell` buffer.

Answer (score 1):

As `sensible-editor` checks your `$EDITOR` environment variable, I would guess this is the culprit.

Converting a comment to answer, I think you probably need to set your `$EDITOR` variable (in your ~/.profile or wherever you manage such things) to either `emacs` or more preferably `emacsclient`, eg.

```
emacsclient -a ''
```

Comment: In a sh-like shell, you might use `set | grep -i emacs | cut -c-100` to look for any other environment variables mentioning emacs which might similarly have outdated values.  (You don't need the `cut`; I've just included it because one of my own matching env values is very very long.)